# Change a textarea's spell-checking language from JavaScript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, spell-checking

I am trying to write a Greasemonkey user-script for Discord that would change a textarea's spell-checking language whenever I switch channels. And I can't seem to understand, how does Firefox assign a dictionary to an element. What I've tried so far:

- Setting `lang` and `xml:lang` on both the textarea and the form.
- Changing the `id` and `name` of both the textarea and the form.
- Setting `spellcheck` to either `true` or `false`.

Is it even possible to “give a hint” to Firefox that this element needs to be spell-checked this way?

Comment: This is most likely determined by the regional version of the client itself, not a setting within the client.

Comment: Javascript and Greasemonkey can't do this, last I checked.  You must write an extension.  Here's [a Firefox extension that may get you closer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/languagetool/?src=external-lt-homepage).

Comment: Setting `element.lang` DOM property works for me in Nightly. Just refocus the element and make sure you have the language actually installed in FF.

Comment: @wOxxOm You are both correct and incorrect. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the `lang` attribute does work, *but only if you don't choose the language manually.* After you have chosen the language, there is no way to undo that unless you:

- Turn off Firefox.
- Go to your profile folder.
- Use SQLite to remove the preference from `content-prefs.sqlite`.

I've filed [an issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1524287) about it on Mozilla's bug tracker. Until then, SQLite is the way apparently.